# Plotly CSS increase bottom line spacing

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I create a plotly plot like this

```
var trace2 = {
    y: [12, 25, 36, 42],
    x: ['20-05-2014', '20-05-2015', '20-05-2016', '20-05-2017'],
    type: 'scatter'
};

var plot_data = [trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('activity-chart', plot_data);
```

**using sample values above**

this is how it looks [image]

the date fields at the bottom doesn't show the whole text, it cuts of the year.
I've tried to use chrome's inspection to edit the css but increasing the space doesn't show the cut text.

Also the title comes from a field in csv field so editing this would require updating alot of fields.

Answer (score 0):

In your `xaxis` you should specify `automargin: true` in combination with `standoff` in your title like this:

```
xaxis: {
    title: { text: 'Datetime', standoff: 50, },
    automargin: true,
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false       
},
```

As your code didn't actually represent the problem I have picked up another code to demonstrate this effect:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
  <script>

    Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/stockdata.csv', function(err, rows){
    function unpack(rows, key) {
      return rows.map(function(row)
      { return row[key]; });}

    var trace = {
      x:unpack(rows, 'Date'),
      y: unpack(rows, 'IBM'),
      mode: 'markers',
      marker: {
        size: 7,
        line: {
        width: 0.5},
        opacity: 0.8},
      type: 'scatter'
    };

    var layout = {
      autosize: false,
      height: 600,
      width: 1200,
      title: 'IBM Stock Data: Jan 2007 - Mar 2016',
      xaxis: {tickvals:['2007-01-01', '2007-09-01', '2008-01-01', '2008-09-01', '2009-01-01', '2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-02-14',  '2012-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'],
              ticktext : ['2007', 'Financial Crisis Starts   ', '2008', 'Financial Crisis Ends   ', '2009', '2010', '2011', 'IBM wins Jeopardy!', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],
              title: {text: 'Datetime', standoff: 50, },
              titlefont: { size: 30 },
              automargin: true,
      },    
      yaxis: {    
          title: 'Value',
          titlefont: { size: 30 },
          automargin: true, 
      },              
    }

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace], layout);
    });

</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

[image]